# Change table row ID dynamically when delete in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

**html**

```
    <table class="table table-bordered listable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th>name</th>
                <th>amount</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-info addRow">+</a>
                 </th>
             </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody class="text-center">
             <tr class="cb" id="row_0">
                <td width="20%">
                  <select class="form-control select2 firstname v1" id="name1_0" name="name[]" style="width: 100%;">
                       <option id="1">tan</option><option id="2">lim</option>
                  </select></td>

                <td width="20%"><input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt1_0" class="form-control first"></td>
                                            
                <td width="20%"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</a></td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary savebtn">Save</button>
```

**Jquery**

```
        $('.addRow').on('click', function(){
            addRow();
          
        });
function addRow()
        {
           var rowCount = $('.listable tr').length -1;
            var tr  = '<tr class="cb" id="row_'+rowCount+'"><td>';
            tr  += '<select class="form-control select2" id="name1_'+rowCount+' first" name="name[]">';
            tr  += '<option id="1">tan</option><option id="2">lim</option></select></td>';
            tr  += '<td><input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt1_'+rowCount+'" class="form-control"></td>';   
           
            tr  += '<td style="text-align:center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</a>';
            tr  += '</td></tr>';    
    i++;
            $('tbody').append(tr);

        }

        $('tbody').on('click', '.remove', function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
        
        $('.savebtn').on('click', function(){
        $('.listable .cb').each(function(index, item){
                console.log($('#amt1_'+index).val());
               
            });
            });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u3hmfc7x/1/

This will dynamically add table rows or delete the row when I click the button. After that, if user deleting the second row, then the row id 2 has been deleted and row id should be interchanged dynamically. Does anyone know how to fix this :(?

For example

```
<tr class="cb" id="row_0"><td>a</td></tr>
<tr class="cb" id="row_1"><td>b</td></tr>
<tr class="cb" id="row_2"><td>c</td></tr>
```

If user delete the second, the rest will auto sequence back the ID, it will become as below

```
  <tr class="cb" id="row_0"><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr class="cb" id="row_1"><td>c</td></tr>
```

Comment: It's really not needed. instead you can delete it based on the index element using the `.eq` & `.remove` method in JQuery.

Comment: Can you explain why you even have / want / need a `id=row_x` - there shouldn't be a need to even have this id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a wiser option, instead of changing the ID, would be to swap the values. You can do that by changing your `onclick` for delete operation to:

```js
        $('tbody').on('click', '.remove', function(){
            elements = $(".cb");
            current = parseInt($(this).id);
            for (let itr = current; itr < elements.length - 1; itr++) {
                elements[itr].value = elements[itr + 1].value;
            }
            elements[elements.length - 1].remove();
            i--;
        });
```

Here's the code for that: https://jsfiddle.net/ckpLqs4g/

Answer (score 2):

you don't need the id to get values from input elements, we can easily get value of each input dynamically, check below code.

```
$('.savebtn').on('click', function(){
   $('.listable .cb').each(function(index, item){
        console.log($(item).find('input[type=number]').val());
   });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n7dzhwk4/

Answer (score 1):

try this,
actually this is not the best method to solve this, you really dont need to change the id dynamically but i hope this will help you

```
$('.addRow').on('click', function(){
            addRow();
          
        });
function addRow()
        {
           var rowCount = $('.listable tr').length -1;
            var tr  = '<tr class="cb" id="row_'+rowCount+'"><td>';
            tr  += '<select class="form-control select2" id="name1_'+rowCount+' first" name="name[]">';
            tr  += '<option id="1">tan</option><option id="2">lim</option></select></td>';
            tr  += '<td><input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt1_'+rowCount+'" class="form-control"></td>';   
           
            tr  += '<td style="text-align:center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</a>';
            tr  += '</td></tr>';    
    i++;
let elementCount = 0
            $('tbody').append(tr);
$('tbody').children('tr').each(function () {
    this.attr('id',`row_${elementCount}`);
  elementCount++;
});

        }

        $('tbody').on('click', '.remove', function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
        
        $('.savebtn').on('click', function(){
        $('.listable .cb').each(function(index, item){
                console.log($('#amt1_'+index).val());
               
            });
            });
```